# AWS SES invalid cc address

Tags: amazon-web-services, smtp, amazon-ses

I have a question about the AWS SES. Let's say I have an invalid address set to cc, and a valid address set to the main address To, in an email. Can the email be sent just like the other smtp, or is it different for AWS SES?

Example)

```
To: cwo@facebook.com
cc: cwo@noreply.111.111.111.111
```

I am asking this question because I am getting the following error log:

> Jan 25 02:19:27 111-111-111-111 postfix/smtp[17111]: C2B522A17EB:
>   to=,
>   relay=email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com[111.111.111.111]:587,
>   delay=1.6, delays=0.01/0.05/1/0.5, dsn=5.0.0, status=bounced (host
>   email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com[111.111.111.111] said: 554
>   Transaction failed: Invalid domain name: 'no-reply.111.111.111.111'.
>   (in reply to end of DATA command))

Comment: You are getting this error becuase your CC is not in email format. Could you please validate it ? http://verifalia.com/validate-email